# Is a Queue a sub-system of a Queue Manager systems or they are completely separate systems?

Tags: queue, messaging, message-queue

In the Message Queuing context:

Can you please explain if a Queue is a sub-system of a Queue Manager?

Or A queue and Queue Manager are completely two separate systems working together?

Answer (score 2):

I say: A queue manager is a container for queues.

Answer (score 0):

## Queue managers

A queue manager is a program that provides messaging services to applications. Applications that use the Message Queue Interface (MQI) can put messages on queues and get messages from queues. The queue manager ensures that messages are sent to the correct queue or are routed to another queue manager. The queue manager processes both the MQI calls that are issued to it, and the commands that are submitted to it (from whatever source). The queue manager generates the appropriate completion codes for each call or command.

The queue managers are the main components in a WebSphere® MQ messaging network. The queue managers host the other objects in the network, such as the queues and the channels that connect the queue managers together. A queue manager must be running to perform the following tasks:

- Start channels
- Process MQI calls
- Create, delete, alter queues and channel definitions
- Run a command server to process MQSC commands

[Reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_qmanagers.htm?lang=en)